# How to save QR code image to server folder once generated ? - PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to generate QR code for each users who signup for my website. I am going to send them QR code in email and they can use that QR code for sign-in. Doing some research work, I found [phpqrcode](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/). I tried the following code of lines, which is saving the name of the QR code image in the DB, but is not saving its image to the folder. How can I save the QR image into any folder(say for example: Uploads). SO once image is uploaded into the folder, I can easily send that image to the user.

So on submitting the register form, the following controller will be called and will save user as well as generate unique QR code for that user.

**signupController.php**

```
$user = \Model\User::loadFromPost();

if($user->save()){

    $tempDir = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].UPLOAD_PATH . 'qrcodes/';
    $codeContents = $user->email;
    $fileName = $user->id.md5($codeContents).'.png';
    $pngAbsoluteFilePath = $tempDir.$fileName; 
    if (!file_exists($pngAbsoluteFilePath)) { 
        QRcode::png($codeContents, $pngAbsoluteFilePath); 
        $user->qrcode = $fileName;
        $user->save();
    } else { 
        echo 'File already generated! We can use this cached file to speed up site on common codes!'; 
        echo '<hr />'; 
    }
}
```

Here `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` is `example.local/` (for Local) and `https://www.example.com/` (for live server) and `UPLOAD_PATH` is `contents/images/uploads`. The above code, saves the name of QR code image file in DB but not saving the image of QR into the uploads folder.

Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have domain as your absolute path. The absolut path has to be path on your server.
So, replace the

```
$tempDir = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].UPLOAD_PATH . 'qrcodes/';
```

with path in format such as

```
$tempDir = __DIR__.DIR_SEPARATOR.UPLOAD_PATH.DIR_SEPARATOR.'qrcodes/';
```

Of course, you need to modify the path according to your server setup but the __ DIR __ contains the path to the directory of the current file.

If you can specify the framework you are working on, I can help you modifying the path.

Comment: Got it. That was the problem. I changed it to Directory and now it works.
I have one more question, How can I scan these QR code when user use it while signin ? So that after scanning they can login to their account .

Comment: @JohnCaverns QR code is just a string encoded in image. So write token in QR code and do auth by this token after receiving token from QR code

Comment: @JohnCaverns what do you mean by "How can I scan them"? Can you please edscribe what exaclty are you trying to accomplish with the QR codes ?

Comment: @mchamuty I mean to say - So now as I have generated this QR for each user as they register. Now say for example, when user come to my application home page within my company campus- they will get the option : Login by QR or Login by email. if they chose Login by QR, camera of that device will be open and they can scan QR code, once scanned, it will check authenticity of the QR code and user. if everything is good, they are allow to continue with our application, else shows error.